# Getting notification on flutter app when Firestore DB is updated using FCM

Tags: firebase, flutter, google-cloud-firestore, firebase-cloud-messaging

I want to send notifications whenever there is an update in my App. Please consider below code for example:

```
import 'package:flutter/material.dart';
import 'package:cloud_firestore/cloud_firestore.dart';
import 'package:firebase_messaging/firebase_messaging.dart';


class ShoppingList extends StatefulWidget {
  _ShoppingListState createState() => _ShoppingListState();
}

class _ShoppingListState extends State<ShoppingList> {

  FirebaseMessaging _firebaseMessaging = new FirebaseMessaging();

  void initState() { 
    super.initState();
    _firebaseMessaging.configure(
      onMessage: (Map<String, dynamic> message){
        print('on message $message');
      },
      onResume: (Map<String, dynamic> message){
        print('on resume $message');
      },
      onLaunch: (Map<String, dynamic> message){
        print('on launch $message');
      },
    );
     _firebaseMessaging.getToken().then((token){
       print(token);
     });


  }
```

Now inside the build method, i have:

```
 FlatButton(
                        child: Icon(Icons.add_shopping_cart),
                        onPressed: () {
                          Firestore.instance
                              .runTransaction((Transaction transaction) async {
                            CollectionReference reference =
                                Firestore.instance.collection('shopping_list');
                            await reference.add({"name": item});
                          });

                          Navigator.of(context).pop();
                        },
                      ),
```

How can I trigger a notification after this action

Comment: You can't send notification from client side. Use Firebase Cloud Functions with firestore trigger

Comment: Sure, thanks for the suggestion.